# Get groups in folder permissions, and export the members of the groups to csv

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to Get the groups authority behind each folder of a drive and the username of each Member of the group, then export it to a CSV File.

The problem is that the group has the directory name before the group e.g. `gescogroup/GR_blablabla`, so I remove `Gescogroup\` using `(Remove(0,12))`.

As you see I first let the user chose the folder of the drive they want to analyze, then the code runs through the folders inside the drive and for each folder it gets the group, then with the name of the group (Removing the "Create owner, "Administrators", "Built "in etc) I should get the members.

My code doesn't work, but I get no errors. Can you guys help me?

```
 cls
    $result = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Select the path of the drive.`n"+"Once the Drive is selected, a excel file will be made with all the informations`n"+"of the selected Harddrive's directory premissions")
    if ($result = "OK")
    {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $FolderBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    [void]$FolderBrowser.ShowDialog()
    $Selection = $FolderBrowser.SelectedPath
    }
    $result2 = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Pleas select where to save your file")
    if ($result2 = "OK")
    {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $FolderBrowser2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    [void]$FolderBrowser2.ShowDialog()
    $FolderBrowser2.Description = "Select where to save your file"
    $Selection2 = $FolderBrowser2.SelectedPath
    }
    $title = "ADPermissions.csv"
    $title2 = "ADPermissions2.csv"
    $ss =$Selection1 -replace '[\W]', ''
    $subtitle = "HardDrive"+ $ss



    $OutFile = ($Selection2+"\"+$subtitle+$title)
    Write-Host = $OutFile



       Remove-Item $OutFile
         $Header = "Folder Path,IdentityReference,names"


            $RootPath = $Selection

            $Folders = dir $RootPath  | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}
      try {
       foreach ($Folder in $Folders){$ACLs = get-acl $Folder.fullname | ForEach-Object { $_.Access  }
                    Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs){
                    if($ACL.IdentityReference -notlike "Administrators" -and $ACL.IdentityReference -notlike "Creator Owner"-and $ACL.IdentityReference -notlike "BUILTIN\Administrators" -and $ACL.IdentityReference -notlike "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -and  $ACL.IdentityReference -notlike "System")
                        {
                       $strAcl = $ACL.IdentityReference


                              $strAcls = $ACL.IdentityReference.ToString()
                              $strUsers=@()
                             $strNames=$strAcls.Remove(0,12)
                             $A = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $strNames -Recursive | Get-ADUser -Property DisplayName | Select Name | Sort-Object Name


                                   foreach($strNames in $A)
                                   {
                                      $strUsers+=$A

                                   }

                           }

                             }
                             }


                                 $OutInfo =  $Folder.fullname + "," + $trAcl+$strUsers
                                Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $OutFile | sort-Object -Unique

                            }catch [System.IO.IOException] {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
try {

        foreach ($Folder in $Folders){$ACLs = get-acl $Folder.fullname | ForEach-Object { $_.Access  }
                Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs){
                if($ACL.IdentityReference -notlike "Administrators" -and $ACL.IdentityReference -notlike "Creator Owner"-and $ACL.IdentityReference -notlike "BUILTIN\Administrators" -and $ACL.IdentityReference -notlike "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -and  $ACL.IdentityReference -notlike "System")
                   {
                            $strAcls = $ACL.IdentityReference.ToString()
                          $strUsers=@()
                         $strNames=$strAcls.Remove(0,12)
                         $A = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $strNames -Recursive | Get-ADUser -Property DisplayName | Select Name | Sort-Object Name

                         foreach ($env:USERNAME in $A){
                          $strUsers +=$env:USERNAME
                         }
                          $OutInfo =  $Folder.fullname + "," + $ACL.IdentityReference + $strUsers
                        }
                       }

                        }
                        }catch [System.IO.IOException] {

    }

}
```

Comment: It's good practice to explain your code, just a few sentences is often enough if it's simple